# How to write parameters in url?

Tags: php, url, parameters, seo

Concerning search engine optimization I wonder what the best practice is to write parameters in a url. Should I place parameter names? Does an id value has a negative effect on search engines?

Here are some options that come to mind:

1. `/project/pid/171/name/my_funny_name`
2. `/project/171/my_funny_name`
3. `/project/my_funny_name`

Comment: You should use `-` instead of `_` as the separator: [SEO Basics: Hyphen or Underscore for SEO URLs?](http://www.ecreativeim.com/blog/2011/03/seo-basics-hyphen-or-underscore-for-seo-urls/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good rule is less params is better. If you need numerical id, 2nd option is quite good, if you force `my_funny_name` part to be unique, you may rely only on this as id. However keep in mind, that if you change name, url will be broken.

Also remember to avoid double names for same content, like `/project/171/my_funny_name` and `/project/171/my_old_name`. Try to use `<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/project/171/my_funny_name">`

Comment: "less params is better", why? :) As programmer it is nice to have parameter names so you do not have to search rewrite rules to understand it.

Comment: Because its simply more user friendly. Remember that SEO is important, but most important is end user experience, ie. it looks better when pasted as url in comments etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the url, you want `AT MINIMUM`, the keywords that people will be searching for to find the page in question.  The id's, in your case, should not have a negative affect.

[Google SEO](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35291)

Answer (score 0):

Having an id value in your url won't have a negative effect, but you should definitely add words before or after your id for SEO. 
What I personnaly like is trying to have a "logical" structure in the url, with id at the beginning, like this :

```
/123_my-category/456_my-great-stuff
```

Concerning the underscore, you should rather use "-", as it is considered as the word separator while _ is more for lisibility, but it's like having the words tied to each other.

Comment: I separated the id to avoid renaming problems. I can lookup the id and can ignore the name. The name is only for the search engine.

Comment: well, you should be able to do the same without separating the id, depends on how you extract it from the url in fact.

Comment: Indeed, I could. Why do you prefer `/123_my-category` instead of `/123/my-category`?

Comment: I see no advantage of `/123_my-category` url over `/123/my-category`. Later one is even more clear in my opinion.

Comment: I prefer having the `id` and `my-category` in the same "directory" (I know it's not a directory) because it defines the same thing, so the structure stays logic, and I can split the url with `/` knowing that every part defines something. With `/123/my-category`, you have to take the first one, the third one, maybe the fifth one... and if for any reason, one is missing, you get the wrong next one. But it's just a choice anyway, it doesn't really matter that much I think ;)